# node.js check if copying new file to disk has finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, polling

I'm trying to write a tethered shooting app with electron / node.js.

The communication between camera and computer is managed by the software, which ships with the camera. The new pictures are directly copied to my local hard disk. After that my app should show the new picture as fast as possible.

I set up a chokidar watcher for the directory where my new pictures arrive. Unfortunately the

`awaitWriteFinish: {stabilityThreshold: 500, pollInterval: 50}`

option of chokidar acts very slowly and sometimes triggers the add-event too early.

My idea to circumvent this was to write my own polling mechanism after the watcher (without awaitWriteFinish option) triggers an event.

I tried fs.stats for polling but fs.stats doesn't recognize the current file size but the total file size.

Is there a easy node.js / javascript / jquery approach to detect if the new file is completely written to disk?

Any help apprechiated.

Comment: Can't you just raise the stabilityThreshold ?

Comment: I can do this, but I hoped that there is a faster approach.

Comment: Short of the software which is writing the file having a notification mechanism, there can't be a faster approach to detecting when a file has finished being written to when the problem is that there are long pauses during the write process.

Comment: Do you think some kind of reload mechanism which tries to load the image and reload on error until loading successful is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could watch the directory for changes. Perhaps scan it first to have a list of files. For example if file you are on Windows and file is saved on C:\temp

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const saveDir = 'C\\temp'

let currentFiles = [];

// Read all cuurent files in directory
fs.readdirSync(saveDir, (error, files) =>
{
  currentFiles = files;
});


fs.watch(saveDir, (eventType, fileName) => 
{
  if (currentFiles.includes(fileName))
  {
    return;
  }
  
  // Handle rename event
  
  // Handle change event
  
});
```

More info here:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener